# OS X "Screen Sharing" increase resolution to match Client

Tags: macos, vnc

Does anyone know how to increase the "Screen Sharing" build in VNC server screen resolution to match the client, instead of being limited to the host (in this case my MacBook Pro resolution)?

Would switching to a different VNC server solve the issue? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Using SwitchResX and a custom resolution that matches the client worked for me, but would corrupt the display on the Macbook Pro.

Use with caution. Probably, well, don't use at all.